# Fragment hide animation is not playing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I'm trying to toggle my fragment with slide animation

Using this code:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();        
SearchPanelFragment existingFragment = (SearchPanelFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag(SearchPanelFragment.FRAGMENT_NAME);        
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.xml.slide_down_search_panel, R.xml.slide_up_search_panel);        
if (existingFragment != null) {
    if (existingFragment.isVisible())
        transaction.remove(existingFragment);       
} else {
    transaction.add(R.id.top_panel_fragment, new SearchPanelFragment(this), SearchPanelFragment.FRAGMENT_NAME);
}

    transaction.commit();
```

So far I get only enter animation on `transaction.add` When is exit animation played? I could only get it when using `transaction.replace` but then I was just swaping an old fragment with identical new one, and what I want is to hide/remove/detach/whatever it's neccessary to make it dissapear with exit animation played

EDIT: I tried hide, remove and detach. No matter what I do, the animation is not played. It's played only on add, show, and replace

EDIT 2:
There might be something wrong with the second animation. Please take a look on both on them. First one slides down and seems to be working just fine.

Slide down

```
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

Slide up

```
<translate
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Edit

[The bug has been fixed as of June 7th 2013.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/495efcad8c8865e3e6f14e4ea3d79cfb1d2410f9) I believe starting at revision 18, the bug has been fixed.

This no longer should be an issue if you are using the latest Support Library Revision

### Old Answer

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32405 There is a bug in support library. The only chance to get it work is get support library sources and recompile it yourself

Comment: Just wondering, this bug (and solution for it) was known at May 29, 2012. Why it is still not fixed?

Comment: It is android style) Some issues are not fixed during years

Comment: oh god, it's still not fixed!

Comment: It has been fixed! Simply use revision 18 or later of the support library.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commit/495efcad8c8865e3e6f14e4ea3d79cfb1d2410f9

Comment: no on Rev22 of suppor library this problem still persists.

Answer (score 9):

You're actually using the wrong function.

According to the documentation for [`setCustomAnimations(int enter, int exit)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int%29):

> Set specific animation resources to run for the fragments that are entering and exiting in this transaction. **These animations will not be played when popping the back stack.**

Instead you should use [`setCustomAnimations (int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> Set specific animation resources to run for the fragments that are entering and exiting in this transaction. **The `popEnter` and `popExit` animations will be played for enter/exit operations specifically when popping the back stack.**